# Set Banana panel custom query

Tags: banana

I have created a Banana custom panel, and I want to change dynamically its "custom query" by a system of "select" tag.

In [this](https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana/wiki/Tutorial:-How-to-Build-a-Custom-Panel) page, I can see that I can find a variable "_d" that contains custom. I can change it by a static variable which I give a value before launch Banana.                                                                             
Far in the tutorial, is a comment "Set the additional custom query", but, I am not sure of what I have to replace by my variable (or have I not to touch it?).

I decided to look at the filtering panel, because, in fact, it is what I want to do (filtering). But I don’t understand how does the module works (where does he stock its filters? and how does it apply them?).

I looked at the filterSrv.js, but I am not sure it do something on filtering/module.js (apart from giving function to filtering/module.js and filtering/module.html).

Do you know something about it?

Answer (score 0):

To set the custom query, you have to set `$scope.panel.queries.custom` in **module.js**. This file `src/app/partials/querySelect.html` is responsible for the Queries tab in each panel's config, where you add custom queries through UI.